# C# How to update IE7 to new version

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

Iam very new to coding so please pardon my lack of knowledge.

I made a program "Music player" that uses [webBrowser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.webbrowser?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) to play video from youtube but from what i understood from other posts it cant work due to webBrowser being IE7. I dont neccessarily have to use webBrowser but it seemed like the best way.

Is there a way to "update" IE or do i need to use different method?

code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace MusicPlayer_V4._1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string _ytUrl;

        


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        public string VideoId
        {
            get
            {
                var ytMatch = new Regex(@"youtu(?:\.be|be\.com) / (?:.*v(?:.*/|=)|(?:.*/)?)([a-zA-Z0-_]+)").Match(_ytUrl);
                return ytMatch.Success ? ytMatch.Groups[1].Value : string.Empty;

            }
        }
        
        //user input (URL)
        private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        //play button
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _ytUrl = txtUrl.Text;
            webBrowser.Navigate($"http://youtube.com/v/{VideoId}?version=3");
        }

        //help button
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        //browser
        private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way moving forward is to use `WebView2` which is basically the same thing as a `WebView` but based on the chromium-based edge. It will be always up to date on windows 10/11 machines and it works down to Windows 7.

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/

Comment: Thanks for help. I should be good from here on.